# c# encoding issue with?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

i have an input like: DisplaygrÃ¶Ãe

And i want output like: Displaygröÿe

With notepad++ problem was solved by: converting to ansi, encoding to utf8 and converting back to ansi.

I need to do this programmatically in c#.

I've tried converting to / from ansi, utf8, latin-1 and none work properly, it shows ? with a function that uses  Encoding.Default.GetBytes, then 
res =  Enconding.Convert(src1,dest1,bytes) and 
EncodingDest.GetChars(res);
where EncodingDest it represent output encoding..

Code is running in Console application, but same result are on WPF.
Doesn't matter with encoding is good for output only if it works, these problems also are for country's like spain, italy or sweden.

Comment: Please be clear. Does the output have to be Ansi? If so, what codepage?

Comment: Need some more information here. Where are you outputting this? Web page, console app, winforms, WPF, web service result?? Ideally, post a code sample.

Comment: And where is the data coming from (in what format/encoding)

Comment: Data are comming from 7 country files (DE,FR,IT,etc), i can read, but not write. Theoretically is UTF-8, don't know exactly.

Comment: @DanM: You need to know what character set your input is in. DisplaygrÃ¶Ãe is what you will see if you take the string "Displaygröße" (suggested by Vlad below) encode it as utf-8, and then incorrectly decode it as latin1. (edit: reversed utf-8/latin1)

Answer (score 2):

use [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("DisplaygrÃ¶Ãe");
var utf8 = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, ascii);
var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8);
```

Comment: @DanM: Did you adjust the example? In the example, `Encoding.ASCII` encoding is used, but you need perhaps `Encoding.Default`.

Comment: yes, but if I read in Unicode, it shows only chinese character and after conversion only ??????

Comment: @DanM: Your input is in ANSI, which must be something like cp1252 (which is not Unicode). Could you please check which codepage is your ANSI?

Comment: ANSI: var e = Encoding.Default;
{System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding}
    [System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding]: {System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding}
    BodyName: "iso-8859-1"
    CodePage: 1252

Comment: @DanM: for me, the following: `utf8.GetString(ansi.GetBytes("DisplaygrÃ¶Ãe"))` produces "Displaygrö�e", which is not what you want, but quite close to. I assume that I chose the wrong encodings. (`utf8` is `Encoding.UTF8`, `ansi` is `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`.

Comment: (@DanM: are you sure you don't want "Displaygröße"?)

Comment: @Vlad: (See my answer) Your suggestion of "Displaygröße" is what he is seeing, if you take "Displaygröße", encode as UTF-8, and then decode as latin1. There is a control character there that you cannot see, which is why your `utf8.GetString(...)` resulted in a question mark. (Unless the control character survived a lot of copy paste!)

Answer (score 1):

When you output a string somewhere (like a `TextWriter`, or a `Stream`, or a `byte[]`), you should always specify the encoding, unless you want the UTF-8 output (the default one):

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"))
    sw.WriteLine("Displaygröÿe");
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't have access to write data. Only to read.

Answer (score 1):

@DanM: You ***need*** to know what character set your input is in.

"DisplaygrÃ¶Ãe" is what you will see if you take the string "Displaygröße" (suggested by Vlad) encode it to bytes as UTF-8, and then incorrectly decode it as latin1.

If you do the same with Displaygröÿe, you would see "DisplaygrÃ¶Ã¿e" (the inverted question mark is literally there, it is not a placeholder for something that can't be displayed.) Technically, "DisplaygrÃ¶Ãe" probably has another character between the `Ã` and `e`, but it is a control code, and is thus invisible to you.

If you have an character set foo, this is true: `my_string = foo_decode(foo_encode(my_string))`. If you have another character set bar, this is true: `barf = bar_decode(foo_encode(my_string))` where `barf` is garbage like you're seeing.

If you don't know what character set your input is in, you will only decode it correctly by chance.

It appears that your input files are in UTF-8, and you will need to decode the bytes from the file as such. (I don't speak enough C# to help you here... I only speak character encodings.)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var rdr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))) {
     result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we had similar problem when sending data to text printer, and only one I get working is this (written as extension):

```
    public static byte[] ToAnsiMemBytes(this string input)
    {
        int length = input.Length;
        byte[] result = new byte[length];

        try
        {
            IntPtr bytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(input);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, result, 0, length);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```